# grid's horizontal scroll displayed on the bottom of the screen outside grid's container

Tags: html, css, ag-grid

I've added ag grid inside a div in like this:

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <app-some-grid />
</div>
```

I've added also css for it:

```css
.grid-container {
  width: 50%;
  height: 400px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Grid has domLayout configed in it's options:

```
 domLayout: 'autoHeight'
```

Grid has something like 50 columns, so it should be scrollable horizontally. And it is in fact, but scrollbar is displayed outside grid-container div on the bottom of the page and it's not displayed correctly as a right side of it is outside a screen. So is right side of grid, so I can't see few last columns of grid. If I resize browser window I can see them. What should I do, to move scrollbar inside a div and force grid to behave properly?

On attached image you can see whole scrollbar with left side visible and right one not visible. On the top you can see bottom, left and right borders of my grid. It's grey on grey but it's visible. If I inspect app and check grid-container div it has proper height of 400px and ends far above scrollbar. It's also far narrower, as you can see by looking at grid's borders.

[image: false scrollbar]

Comment: Try to share your code on an online editor like CodeSandbox or Plunkr

Answer (score 0):

1. try using max-width instead of width to .grid-container
2. add max-width: 100% to grid

it's best idea to use background color to check what's wrong.